# Can't build in visual studio 2015 because 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v14.0.dll' cannot be found

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

When attempting to build in visual studio 2015, the following file is missing? This project was previously being built in VS2013.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      The task factory
>   "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v14.0.dll". Could
>   not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v14.0.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Try removing and adding the references again may help you.

Comment: Update NuGet packages helped me

Comment: Make sure you have selected Windows Workflow Foundation in the VS Individual Components, That's how i fixed the issue. See below same, https://johnlouros.com/blog/how-to-fix-VS2017-missing-XAML-tools-build-error

Answer (score 60):

The assembly has been renamed. Change on the CodeTaskFactory MSBuild Task the AssemblyFile parameter to...(in your error there should be a targets file name where this task resides)

```
AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"
```

Chances are someone tried to be clever and use an MSBuild property like this..(which doesn't work for MSBuild 14 but would for 12)...

```
AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll"
```

Just fyi...There are some others as well such as `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0.dll` has been renamed to `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll`

Comment: I saw this error after installing a package via Nuget. To fix, I edited the .targets file under the package folder as described in Gary's answer. I just wanted to point out that the location that needs to be edited may not be obvious from the error, especially if the cause is a recent package install.

Comment: Why does `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets` reference `$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll`? Surely that will fail when ToolsVersion is 14.0 ?

Comment: I ran into this problem while working on a Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 trying to run a task for the Yahoo Yui Compressor build.  I had to update the ls.pubignore.wpp.targets to replace the v$(MSBuildingToolsVersion) with Core  I left the $(MSBuildingToolsPath) at the beginning.

Comment: So what do we do if the assembly having the issue in a dll we don't own?

Comment: @BobBlack, where is this package folder normally located?

Comment: The target file is located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets

Answer (score 26):

What helped me with Visual Studio 2017 is to copy Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll and rename it to Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v15.0.dll
[image: build.tasks.v15.0.dll]

Comment: It worked for me to. But the real question should be: Why did I have to do that?

Comment: Didn't help to me.

Comment: Renaming the dll worked for me only after restarting Visual Studio

Answer (score 21):

In my case that was a problem of SFML.NET nuget package.

It depended upon outdated Nuget Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output component, which was the reason why build failed.

After i manually updated to .Net 4.6, deleted all nuget staff from project file and deleted its files from project and readded all dependencies again version of Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output was changed and viola!

Comment: `Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output` was the cause of my issues as well. Simply updating that was enough to fix it.

Comment: Same here.  Just updated package in Nuget and build was fine.

Comment: @Kris McGinnes, add your comment as an answer and I will upvote it.  It resolved my issue, and apparently GeoffCoope's as well.

Comment: Thanks @RichardII. Feel free to up vote my comment, but I don't think it warrants an entirely new answer. It would be too similar to drweb86's answer.

Comment: As Kris McGinnes says, **Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output**, which for me came with the GeckoFX webbrowser component.

Answer (score 9):

First time I restart visual studio, worked for me

Second time I got this error again  and I did update:

`Install-Package Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output -Version 2.2.0-xbuild02`

Comment: Not sure why it worked, or what it is doing. OP would you be able to elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

It was enough for me to just restart Visual Studio.

I suspect that I had earlier killed all my MSBuild.exe processes doing something else and that not having any MSBuild.exe processes causes the error.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from Gary's answer I parameterized this as follows:

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(MSBuildToolsVersion)'=='14.0'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TasksAssemblyName>Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core</TasksAssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TasksAssemblyName>Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion)</TasksAssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
<UsingTask TaskName="SecondsSinceEpoch" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\$(TasksAssemblyName).dll">
```

Comment: What about where `MSBuildToolsVersion` is later than '14.0'? Your condition is not future-proof and will revert to the previous naming convention for later versions. You should check if `MSBuildToolsVersion` is greater than '14.0', but I'm not sure that this is a trivial task because you're dealing with strings. It might be better to assume the change to be a breaking change and upgrade any build servers/agents that are on the old version.

Answer (score 2):

My solution: removing two rows from the "*.csproj" file:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I removed "ls.pubignore.wpp.targets" file from root. and It removed the error. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case 
I updated some of the packages from NuGet package manager in VS2015, then tried to open the same solution in vs2013 in another machine where vs2015 was not installed.

Installing Microsoft Build Tools 2015 has resolved the error. That adds Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll to the GAC, which I think is what makes it work.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Answer (score 1):

Update the "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" from nuget packages and it resolves my error and this is the best solution ,after a multiple try i found out a solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by renaming `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets` to something MSBuild and VS 2015 couldn't find

Weird that the bad AssemblyTasks reference was in a file outside the repo I was compiling, that I should not have to edit. But I have been working with several different versions of Visual Studio, I'm not surprised one got its wires crossed.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017 this is what worked for me, it's a mix of two provided solutions. Neither worked on their own so this is why I'm submitting this as a new answer.

In the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets`

Replace `AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">` with `AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">`

And then copy the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll` in the same folder with the name `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v15.0.dll`

Answer (score 0):

For me I was converting from building our solution using `msbuild` to using `dotnet build`. Updating from codedom 2.0.1 -> 3.6.0 allowed the solution to build.