# Does my jenkins slave need to have a user named Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

Jenkins builds started to fail today with the following error.

```
error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded
from the assembly "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll". Could not
find a part of the path
'C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\05all4b4.tmp'.
```

A similar but slightly different error occurs if I try to build with msbuild14.  The C:\Users\Jenkins path does not exist and I'm not aware of ever having a user named Jenkins on the build machine.  I think that is clearly part of the problem, but I see nothing in Jenkins master-slave configuration docs that suggest that I need to create a special user account named Jenkins.  How can I resolve this error?  I'd appreciate if anyone that might have seen this issue in the past could tell me how it was fixed in that situation.

The master and slave machines are windows servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the issue in my case.  For some reason I had to recreate the following directory structure.
C:\Users**Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp**

The Jenkins user directory had been deleted somehow.  There is no Jenkins user account, and the sub-folders under Users is typically for user accounts so I would have never guessed that such a directory would need to exist.  Using the error message I just recreated the path, and then gave a jenkins service account full control, recursively, starting at that Jenkins directory.

To answer my own question, it appears that a user account named jenkins is not needed but somehow during the slave setup that path gets created with the correct permissions.  If that path gets deleted for some reason, then the jenkins service cannot recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your case, but I have seen a similar error and it was due to renamed MS Build assembly. On the slave we had Visual Studio 2012, the same version was on the master, the project was created with Visual Studio 2012, but our build server was with newly installed Visual Studio 2015. I changed in the project file the CodeTaskFactory MSBuild Task, the AssemblyFile parameter, for more information check [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722877/cant-build-in-visual-studio-2015-because-microsoft-build-tasks-v14-0-dll-cann)

Please check Visual Studio/.Net versions on the machines, you could also see in the control panel if something has been installed recently.

I have not seen any requirement for Jenkins slave machine to have user named jenkins, although on Ubuntu the jenkins process on the master is with username jenkins (I believe it is the same for Windows).

Comment: Thanks for the effort to post an answer.  The confirmation that a jenkins slave doesn't need a jenkins user is helpful.  That does answer the question in the title of my post, and I added an answer to the second question of how to resolve my specific situation.